# Invitation letter format

Tags: visas, paperwork, turkey, applications

I am planning to invite my friend to Turkey so I figured I need to prepare an invitation letter. However I couldn't find a specific format. Can I have a sample or a format that fulfills the Turkey visa requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I was issued a similar kind of invitation letter for a conference. I hope this will help you

> The Visa Officer, [Country Name] Embassy
>
> Subject: Invitation Letter
>
> Dear Sir/Madame, Please accept this letter as a formal invitation for
>   [Full Name] .that has been invited to attend the [purpose for
>   invitation], held at [location, complete address], [date]
>
> Below are the passport details of [Full Name]   Full Name
>       
>   Position
>             Organization
>     Passport No:
>        
>   Expiry Date
>      Date of Birth
>     Nationality
>
> Please note that all expenses during the [purpose] will be covered by
>   [name / organization who is sending the invitation letter].
>
> We, therefore, request that a [visa type] be issued to [full name]  to
>   enable him to travel to [Location] to attend [purpose of invitation].
>
> If you require any further clarification or information, please do not
>   hesitate to contact the undersigned.